# Checking if input is an integer, and inputting more than 1 character results in multiple statements being printed in console instead of just once

Tags: c++

```
    {
        valid = true; //Assume the cin will be an integer.
        cin >> menuValue;

        if (cin.fail()) //cin.fail() checks to see if the value in the cin
                        //stream is the correct type, if not it returns true,
                        //false otherwise.
        {
            cin.clear();  //This corrects the stream.
            cin.ignore(); //This skips the left over stream data.
            cout << "Please enter an Integer from 1-6 only." << endl;
            valid = false; //The cin was not an integer so try again.
        }
    }
```

Im trying to make an error checkpoint, where is a user inputs something that isn't an integer, it'll ask them to rein put the number, the only issue is If I were to input something such as jiasdhais, it would print the same message as many times as the length of the input. Any way around this?

Comment: I found the base code on cplusplus.com

Comment: `cin.ignore()` only discards a single character https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore

Comment: @SandipMishra You may have found why cplusplus.com is often loudly mocked around here in one of the easiest possible ways.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{
    int input;
    if( !( std::cin >> input) ){
        //in case of fail do stuff
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    } else {
        //then check for 1-6
        //your code ...
    }
}
```

If input is not integer it will be discarded.More specifically if your architecture holds int as 4bytes then the input should be in range -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, otherwise will be discarded.

Comment: Kindaof, with a bit of tweaking I made it work, however now the issue is that the code will only recognize the new input after a few lines, as in I need to press enter 2-3 times then input the value.

Comment: ``` 
    while (isInputValid == false)
    {
        if (!(cin >> menuValue) || menuValue > 6 || menuValue < 1)
        {
            //in case of fail do stuff
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            printf("Please Enter a valid Menu Option!");
            cin >> menuValue;
            pressEnter();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
 ```

Comment: Please look here I didn't get your question. (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output)

Comment: try `std::cin.get();` for your **press enter** @SandipMishra